# grep for an alphanumeric strings of any length with a colon on each side

Tags: bash, command-line, grep, regular-expression

How would you grep for an alphanumeric strings of 1 to 50 characters (ideally, any length would work too) with a colon on each side – a typical result would be all the lines containing the string `:shopping:`. So far I've got the code below (I've tried some variations on it) which doesn't work:

```
grep ':[[:alnum:]]{1,100}:' ~/x.txt
```

Comment: You just need to enable the extended regex capabilities of `grep` by including the `-E` switch.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to enable extended regular expressions for this:

```
grep -E ':[[:alnum:]]+:' ~/x.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

With basic regular expressions, you can write it like:

```
grep ':[[:alnum:]]\{1,100\}:' ~/x.txt
```

Note that `\{` (as opposed to `\+` or `\?` for instance) is standard and portable, and actually the BRE equivalents of `+` and `?` are typically written with `\{`: `\{1,\}` and `\{0,1\}`. `grep -E` is also standard and portable though, so you might as well use it as it makes for more readable regexps in those cases.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a extended regular expresion so you need to use the -E option:

```
grep -E ':[[:alnum:]]{1,100}:' ~/x.txt
```

Comment: thanks! I put the other answer as correct because I did not write up my "ideal" script in the headline, and I don't want to cause people who google for an answer to copy paste the wrong answer, but I'll use yours. :)

Comment: @TorThommesen - you can edit the title of your Q if it's not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Since no one else mentioned it, you may also use `egrep`, which, as I understand it, is equivalent to `grep -E`.

```
egrep ':[[:alnum:]]{1,100}:' ~/x.txt
```

Comment: `egrep` was the historical command to grep with EREs. The functionality of grep and egrep have since (a long ago) been merged into grep with the -E option. `egrep` is now considered obsolete/deprecated (but unlikely to go as some people are still used to it).